# How to pass parameters via the selector/action?

Tags: rubymotion

Is there a way to pass parameters via the addTarget call as it calls another function?

I've also tried the sender method - but that seems to break as well. What's the correct way to pass the parameters without creating global variables?

```
@my_button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
@my_button.frame = [[110,180],[100,37]]
@my_button.setTitle("Press Me", forState:UIControlStateNormal)
@my_button.setTitle("Impressive!", forState:UIControlStateHighlighted)

# events
newtext = "hello world"
@my_button.addTarget(self, action:'buttonIsPressed(newtext)', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown)
view.addSubview(@my_button)


def buttonIsPressed (passText)

   message = "Button was pressed down - " + passText.to_s
   NSLog(message)

end
```

Update:

OK, here's a method with an instance variable that worked.

```
@my_button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
@my_button.frame = [[110,180],[100,37]]
@my_button.setTitle("Press Me", forState:UIControlStateNormal)
@my_button.setTitle("Impressive!", forState:UIControlStateHighlighted)

# events
@newtext = "hello world"
@my_button.addTarget(self, action:'buttonIsPressed', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown)
view.addSubview(@my_button)


def buttonIsPressed     
   message = "Button was pressed down - " + @newtext
   NSLog(message)
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way of attaching "parameters" to a rubymotion `UIButton` call is through the use of tags.

First set up a button with a `tag` attribute.  This tag is the parameter you want to pass to the target function.

```
@button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
@button.setTitle "MyButton", forState:UIControlStateNormal
@button.frame =[[0,0],[100,50]]
@button.tag = 1
@button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:",  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

Now create a method that accepts `sender` as a parameter:

```
def buttonClicked(sender)
    mytag = sender.tag

   #Do Magical Stuff Here
end
```

Forewarning:  As far as I know, the tag attribute only accepts integer values.  You could get around this by putting your logic into the target function like this:

```
def buttonClicked(sender)
    mytag = sender.tag

    if mytag == 1
      string = "Foo"

    else
      string = "Bar"
    end

end
```

Initially I tried setting the action with `action: :buttonClicked` which worked but did not allow for using the `sender` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you usually create instance variables in your Controller class, and then just call methods on them from any method.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) using `setTitle` is the general way to set a title of a `UIButton` instance. So you're doing it right.